# Higher degree First order differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, factoring

I'm having trouble solving this type of differential equation:

$$(x^2y'-xy)\left(y'+\frac{x}{y}\right)=2y'$$
I tried using clairaut's equation or using equations solvable for P but I haven't got anything to work. I tried factoring and isolating variables but it seems impossible any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: is this correct:$$(x^2y'-xy)(y'+\frac{x}{y})=2y'$$

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't know how to put it in fraction.

Comment: Done ! Just have a look in the post : it is quite simple.

Comment: Did you isolate a variable? I tried isolating y but I can't do it since there is a y in the denominator.

Comment: Sorry : when I wrote *done* I was speaking about the edit of the equation; nothing else. I do not know where you did catch this problem but, at least to me, it looks monstreous !

Comment: @CzarLuc Check your equation. Is that typed correctly?

Comment: Yes, is it possible that it is unsolvable?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by context?

Comment: Where did you find this equation ?

Comment: It's a problem given by my professor. He hinted out that it could be solved by using Clairaut's equation but so far I have no luck in isolating the y variable.